# datetime picker, set value Today using jquery

Tags: jquery

I try using Php, but i realize that i need this working on the client side. 
"ready" function is working

```
//fechaMin and fechaMax are Inputs type="datetime"
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("#fechaMin").val(Date.now()-1); //This one value: Yesterday
  $("#fechaMax").val(Date.now());

  });
});
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: can you please give out your code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You just doubled the curled and round brackets There should be a script error on your console. Getting rid of the redundant brackets will make ready work fine I guess?

Comment: Um, all i need is to set the value of those datetimes inputs to today value and yesterday value, all inside the ready function should work but .val(Date.now()) is not working, im not sure why

I dont have more code than this for this situation

Comment: What browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4afk3c1v/

```
$(function() {

    var yesterday = new Date;
    yesterday = yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
    yesterday = $.datepicker.formatDate( "m/d/yy",new Date(yesterday));

    var today = $.datepicker.formatDate( "m/d/yy",new Date);

    $( "#fechaMin").val(yesterday).datepicker();
    $( "#fechaMax").val(today).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

dm4web, thanks for your answer, and yes, i see it works, but not in my project =/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    //The date-inputs are inside the registrosFiltros.php file, so i call it to the index (i need this in this way)
    $('#filtrosContenido').load('php/registrosFiltros.php', function(data) {
        $(this).html(data);
    });

    var yesterday = new Date;
    yesterday = yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
    yesterday = $.datepicker.formatDate( "m/d/yy",new Date(yesterday));

    var today = $.datepicker.formatDate( "m/d/yy",new Date);

    $( "#fechaMin").val(yesterday).datepicker();
    $( "#fechaMax").val(today).datepicker();


    $(document).on('change', '.filtro', function(e) {
        actualizarListaFormatos();
    });
});
```